# Is it possible to automatically create a widget from a shortcut - Swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift, widget, sirishortcuts

After doing some research I discovered that a user can make a shortcut a widget by holding down on the home-screen, pressing the top left button, searching for "shortcuts", and then tapping on the specific shortcut.

From this [article](https://www.avanderlee.com/swift/siri-support-nsuseractivity/) I discovered that it's possible to automatically create a shortcut for the user (they don't have to physically add a shortcut in the shortcuts app that your app donated, instead they can just click a button).

Thus, I was wondering if it's also possible to create a widget for a shortcut you defined, where all the user has to do is tap a button within your app, instead of going through the whole search process.

Thanks